# Using dplyr and lazyeval with '...'

Tags: r

#### Simplifying Edit:

It comes down to this:

```
df = data.frame(a = 1:10)

#example function that takes optional arguments
mymean <- function(x, w = 1, s = 0) { s + mean(w * x) }

summarize_(df, m = "mean(a)")
#>     m
#> 1 5.5

summarize_(df, m = "mymean(a)")
#> Error: could not find function "mymean"
```

According to `vignette("nse") summarize_ must be given the formula syntax when using non-standard summarizing functions.

Ultimately, I want to be able to wrap `summarize_` in a function like so:

```
my_summary <- function(df, x, ...) {
  summarize_(df, 
             m = "mean(a)",
             wm = "mymean(a, ...)" #gives error 
}

#Partial working function
my_summary <- function(df, x, ...) {
  summarize_(df, 
             m = "mean(a)", #works
             wm1 = interp(mymean(a), a = as.name(x) #works but doesn't  allow ... 
             wm2 = interp(mymean(a, b), 
                          .values=list(a = as.name(x),
                                       b = quote(...)),  #doesn't work
             wm3 = interp(mymean(a, ...), a = as.name(x) #doesn't work
}
```

A working function would allow me to call:

```
my_summary(df, a)
#> 5.5

my_summary(df, a, w=5, s=2)
#> 29.5
```

Comment: Why can't you just do `summarize(df, m = mymean(a))`?

Comment: Why specify the function as a string? That’s almost certainly not required, nor a good idea.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I'm trying to substitute in the variables in "...". The other option is to pass it as `~mymean(a, ...)`, but then the `...` are not correctly interpreted. If I could pass it as a string, I could explicitly build the string before the `summarize_ call`, and then pass the expanded `...` as part of the string.

Comment: @potterzot See my answer. No need for strings but it *is* somewhat complicated, admittedly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the problem is passing `...` to the function, one solution is to construct the call via `call` and `do.call` (yes, both):

```r
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(a = 1:10)

mymean = function(x, w = 1, s = 0)
    s + mean(w * x)

my_summary = function (df, x, ...) {
    x = as.name(substitute(x))
    mycall = do.call(call, c('mymean', quote(x), list(...)))
    summarize_(df,
               m = lazyeval::interp(~mean(x), x = x),
               w = lazyeval::lazy_(mycall, environment()))
}

my_summary(df, a)
#>     m   w
#> 1 5.5 5.5
my_summary(df, a, w = 5, s = 2)
#>     m    w
#> 1 5.5 29.5
```

Incidentally, the above also fixes passing the column name — I couldn’t get your code to work, and I don’t think it *would* work that way.

Comment: `call` and `do.call` are something I need to study more... Thanks for the great solution!

Comment: To be honest, I’m not entirely clear myself on why `do.call` is needed here at all. My initial thought was that you’d need it but now that I think about it, `call('mymean', quote(x), ...)` should also work. Except, it doesn’t. Apparently my first instinct was right.

Comment: I spent some more time on this and came up with the following, which seems to match the output from your code. Thought you might be interested:

Answer (score 0):

This very hacky, horrible function does the trick, but what if `mymean` contains many optional arguments?

```r
mymean <- function(x, w=1, s = 0) { s + mean(w * x) }

my_summarize <- function(df, x, ...) {
  vlist = list(...)
  vlist_names = names(vlist)
  if ("w" %in% vlist_names & "s" %in% vlist_names) {
    res = summarize_(df, m = interp(~mymean(a, w=b, s=c), 
                                    .values = list(a = as.name(x),
                                                   b = vlist$w,
                                                   c = vlist$s)))
  }
  else if ("w" %in% vlist_names) {
    res = summarize_(df, m = interp(~mymean(a, w=b), 
                                    .values = list(a = as.name(x),
                                                   b = vlist$w)))
  }
  else if ("s" %in% vlist_names) {
    res = summarize_(df, m = interp(~mymean(a, s=c), 
                                    .values = list(a = as.name(x),
                                                   c = vlist$s)))
  }
  else {
    res = summarize_(df, m = interp(~mymean(a), a = as.name(x)))
  }
  res    
}


df = data.frame(a = 1:10)

my_summarize(df, "a")
#>     m
#> 1 5.5
my_summarize(df, "a", s=5)
#>      m
#> 1 10.5
my_summarize(df, "a", w=2)
#>    m
#> 1 11
my_summarize(df, "a", w=2, s=5)
#>    m
#> 1 16
```